# Counting couples of equal sets

Tags: combinatorics

Let $S= \{\, 1, 2, ..., n \,\}$
I'm trying to find how many possibilities are there for couples $ (S_1, S_2) $, where $S_1, S_2 \in S$ such that $S_1 = S_2$ ($S_1 = S_2$ if $S_1 = \{\,1, 4 \,\}$ and $S_2 = \{\,4, 1 \,\}$ for example).

I gave this my best but failed to figure this out.. Any help?

Comment: Do you mean $S_1,S_2\subseteq S$ rather than $S_1,S_2\in S$? That sounds like a convoluted way of counting how many different subsets $S$ has -- for each such subset $S_1$ you can form $(S_1,S_1)$ -- and conversely, each pair of two equal elements is completely determined by its first element.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the couples $(S_1, S_2)$, such that $S_1, S_2\subseteq S$ and $S_1 = S_2$, you are looking for all the couples $(S_1, S_1)$, such that $S_1\subseteq S$. Here, $S_1$ can be an arbitrary subset of $S$, hence, the number of couples equals the number of subsets of $S$, which is $2^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Given $k$ between $0$ and $n$, there will be
$$
\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}=\frac{n\cdot(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{1\cdot 2\cdots k}
$$
distinct subsets of $S$ with $k$ elements. For each such subset, its $k$ elements can be arranged in $k!=1\cdot 2\cdots k$ different orders. If we then were to pick two different orders representing the same $k$-element subset, this could be done in
$$
\binom{k!}{2}=\frac{k!(k!-1)}{2}
$$
ways. Clearly we need more than $1$ element in the subset to be able to order it in multiple ways, so we need only consider $k\geq 2$. This results in
$$
f(n):=\sum_{k=2}^n\binom nk\binom{k!}2
$$
such pairs.

---

Here are a few figures:
$$
\begin{array}{|r|ccccccc|}
\hline
n&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
\hline
f(n)&1&18&342&8680&306135&14670306&922084828\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
Computed using [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=table%20sum_k%3D2%5En%20binom(n,k)*binom(k!,2)%20for%20n%20%3D%202%20to%208).